# M getting fatal error: cannot decrement before startIndex.please resolve

Tags: swift

Getting an fatal error when I'm trying execute the following code:

```
 let truncated = "{" + stringToSend.substring(to: stringToSend.characters.index(before: stringToSend.endIndex)) + "}"
                //stringToSend = "tttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt" + truncated + "@"
```

Comment: What is your `stringToSend`?

Answer (score 1):

Your error occurs because your string is empty or has only one character.

A simple `if` can fix it.

Swift 3

```
if stringToSend.count > 1{
   let truncated = stringToSend.substring(to: stringToSend.characters.index(before: stringToSend.endIndex))
}
```

Swift 4:

```
if stringToSend.count > 1{
   let truncated = String(stringToSend[stringToSend.startIndex...stringToSend.index(before: stringToSend.endIndex)])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if `stringToSend` is empty.

The code gets the index `before` the `endIndex`. If the string is empty the index `before` the `endIndex` is *before startIndex* which raises an exception.

Solution: Make sure that `stringToSend` is not empty